# mysql connector .net 6.2.2 web providers not installing on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to install the mysql connector .net 6.2.2 on a Windows Server 2008 64bit without any succes.

It seems that the Web Providers give an error when installing, but I can't find the reason for this. On my local machine everything works fine.

Comment: Providing the error message would be very helpful for people to help you determine an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a Mysql bug. I needed the most recent mysql.data.msi version 6.4.4. and I was trying 6.2.2...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the [connector library from Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data), that way you can also move that dependency state from the server and into the application. This will make it easier to move the application around and deploy it other places.

Comment: I think you can use nuget from the command line: http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939